# Can't find System.Windows MvvmCross xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

When I build for the iPhone simulator all seems to work fine. However, when I build for the iPhone, I get messages saying the following -

> Warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly 'Cirrious.CrossCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819' was not found. Please review the project's references. (MT3005) (IMI.Webstore.Mobile)

This worked with previous versions of Xamarin but the current beta release seems to have broken something. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Mono version of the System.Windows assembly supplied by Xamarin?

Comment: @Stuart I have not yet tried this. I will give it a shot and upodate. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the build log further, it actually wasn't a problem with finding that particular dll, even though there were warnings about it.

The issue was actually with some directory permissions due to a some what complicated windows VM setup. I ended up cloning a copy of the code base into a different directory and the issue sorted itself out. PHEW!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference System.Windows in your Touch Project.